# how to set framelayout to landscape even if my activity is in portrait mode in android 2.3.1

Tags: android, camera, landscape, portrait

i have an activity where i am opening a camera. i am using framelayout for camera preview. but i have to open camera in portrait mode which creating lot many problem, like small screen, rotation problem, can i set my framelayout to landscape even if my activity is in portrait mode

or if any idea for opening camera effectively in portrait mode will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In API level 8 (v2.2), Camera contains a method called setDisplayOrientation. Call this method with 90 to rotate your camera display to portrait mode.

Comment: i tried this but i am getting very small preview on screen. can you provide me any link for setting camera full screen in portrait mode

Comment: Set both your activity to portrait in AndroidManifest.xml <Activity android:screenOrientation="portrait"/> and call setDisplayOrientation(90).

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your AndroidManifest.xml's activity declaration:

```
<Activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" ... />
```